# Communication between two unrelated classes in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oop

I'm fairly new to rails and I've run into a scenario that I'm having trouble solving "the right way".

Let's say I have a few models:

- Comment
- Article
- Photo
- Video

Comments can be made on Articles, Photos, Videos and other Comments (as replies).  More generally, comments can potentially be made on any object.

What I need is to be able to call methods on the object that the comment was made on (without knowing what that object is).

My current strategy is to rely on duck typing and simply define an informal "protocol" for accessing properties I need.

In my Comment class I have a method `commentable_object` which returns the thing that was commented on (either a Photo, Video, Article or Comment).  Then on this `commentable_object` I call two methods: `notification_user` and `notification_object`.  It's the responsibility of the commetable_object to implement `notification_user` and `notification_object` and return the appropriate thing.

[image]

The details of these methods is not important, what's important is that my Comment class needs to request specific data from *some* class (which can be anything).

The problem is I don't want all these different classes to know about the Comment class.  Right now I'm relying on duck typing and simply checking respond_to on these objects.  It just feels weird for Article, Photo and Video to implement methods that are needed by the Comment class when really they shouldn't know anything about it.  Is there perhaps a better place to implement these methods?

What's the most elegant way to implement this in rails?

**UPDATE**

Just to be a bit more clear, I'm not looking for ways to model the relationships between these objects.  My question is really about how to cleanly define an "interface" used between two objects but without those two objects knowing about each other.

Comment: I'd define a single method in all the commented classes which would provide you with the information needed. Hard to develop without details but you;re following the good path with duck typing

Answer (score 2):

in rails it is called polymorphic associations see this, it may help:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association

Comment: your answer is out of subject :)

Comment: I'm aware of polymorphic associations.  What I'm trying to figure out is how to cleanly define methods in the commetable classes so that I can call methods on them like my_comment.commentable.do_something_that_comments_need().  But I don't want to implement all these comment-specific methods in all the classes because they shouldn't know about comments.  I'm just wondering if there's a clean way to do this in rails without polluting the model class.

Comment: damn, it is really so, sorry for my inattention. but i won't delete my post, maybe it will be interesting to author of the question

Comment: @IlyaBoltnev Yeah you should leave your answer because it is somewhat related (and coincidentally the link you left is exactly about comments which is cool).  My question is a little more related to the communication between one class and the 'commentable' polymorphic class specifically with regards to the interface and protocol used by both classes.